# Free streaming server for Voip server

Tags: media, voip, audio-streaming

I need an open-source application which streams on demand (RTSP?) the prerecorded files. It should support all major codecs (G.711,g729...), and must be reasonably efficient.

Up until now Ive found only VLAN player suitable for this task. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mediastremer2 sdk was good enough for me.

But live555 media server did the job as simple RTSP servers

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have an [asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) machine with all major codecs. Get g729/g723 on: [asterisk.hosting.lv](http://asterisk.hosting.lv/). Don't forget that in some countries it is illegal to use g729/g723 without paying for them.

Anyway back to your question. In your Asterisk dial plan you could playback the prerecorded file like:

```
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
exten => _X.,n,Playback(/path/to/file)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

When I make a call going to that context I get to hear the file. Is that what it is you want to do?

Also have a look on [voip-info.org](http://voip-info.org). There is lots of knowledge there.

edit:

Also note that asterisk has a MusicOnHold diaplan utility which you can use to stream FM-radio streams. You might want to have a look on [a blog post I wrote](http://blog.mserver.nl/2008/07/09/asterisk-playing-audio-streams/) last year. So in a sense you could have VLAN player or something else to act as a streaming server and use asterisk to VoIP it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try SIPp. Version 3.4 onward supports RTP streaming for PCMA, PCMU and G729. You can enable G723 codec in the source as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have used [rtpplay](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/irt/software/rtptools/) to send audio files to a specified ip/port. That's at least a good place to start